# Pspice: FFT and distortion in output file does not coincide

Tags: spice, pspice, distortion

I don't understand how Pspice calculate the distortion factor of a signal. I have this 1kHz output signal from an amplifier, and here is the FFT with 10 montecarlo simulation (zoomed):

[image]

In the "output file options" I checked "Perform Fourier Analysis", center frequency "1000", number of harmonics "5" and output variables "V(OUT)".

In the output file, I obtain that:

[image]

Which is an enormous difference from the distortion I have calculated from FFT.

In the FFT, the sum of the 5 harmonics (picking the worst case in each and 1kHz excluded, so one more harmonic than the program consider in the output file) is only 850uV, and from 22V this is a -88dB difference: 0.0039% THD.

For the output file, the third harmonic alone is higher than this value, and yet in the FFT is not only this much but also much lower than the second (all the montecarlo, as you can see).

EDIT: also, the sum of the Fourier Component does not match the THD, that is strange too, and setting harmonics to only one result in a different THD that still does not match the Fourier Component.

What is happening? How Pspice Fourier analysis does calculate the distortion and why it does not coincide with the FFT graph?

This is not happening in LTSpice (the other SPICE program), where the distortion is exactly like the FFT.

Also, here is the complete FFT:

[image]

Comment: Please keep the argument civil, don't focus on the person but focus on the problem. Thanks